# php/symfony: retrieving an attribute in the url for POST/PUT api

Tags: php, symfony

For a datatable I use in a page (webix datatable), I have to use a REST API.

My url is for example: http://localhost:8000/trial/1

In this page to make the api call I use the following:

```
save: "rest->{{ path('api_i_post') }}",
url: "rest->{{ path('erp_interventionapi_get', { trialid: trial.id })
```

With the GET method, I retrieve for a trial (/trial/1), many interventions which are loaded from a database and filled in the datatable.

With this datatable, I'm able to "add a new row". It uses the POST method (save: "rest->{{ path('api_i_post') }}")

When I add a new row, I'd like to be able to get the field trial_id filled in automatically, depending from where I add a new row in the datatable (for /trial/1, trial_id = 1) but I don't know how to retrieve this attribute (or the trial object id), in a POST and a PUT.

My postAction:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post("/api_i/", name="api_i_post")
 */
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = new Intervention;
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $action = $request->get('action');
    $daadala = $request->get('daadala');
    $date = $request->get('date');
    $week = $request->get('week');
    $infopm = $request->get('info_pm');
    $comment = $request->get('comment');
    $location = $request->get('location');
    $trial = $request->get('trialid');

    $data->setAction($action);
    $data->setDaadala($daadala);
    $data->setDate($date);
    $data->setWeek($week);
    $data->setWho($infopm);
    $data->setInfoPm($comment);
    $data->setComment($location);
    $data->setTrial($trial);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();

    $lastid = $data->getId();

    $response=array("id" => $id, "status" => "success", "newid" => $lastid);
    return new JsonResponse($response);

    $view = View::create(array("newid" => $lastid, "id" => $id, "status" => "success"));
    return $this->handleView($view);

}
```

And my putAction

```
    /**
 * @Rest\Put("/api_i/{id}")
 */
public function putAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = new Intervention;
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $action = $request->get('action');
    $daadala = $request->get('daadala');
    $date = $request->get('date');
    $week = $request->get('week');
    $infopm = $request->get('info_pm');
    $comment = $request->get('comment');
    $location = $request->get('location');
    $sn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $intervention = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ErpBundle:Sponsor')->find($id);

    if (empty($intervention)) {
        return new View("Sponsor not found", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
    $intervention->setAction($action);
    $intervention->setDaadala($daadala);
    $intervention->setDate($date);
    $intervention->setWeek($week);
    $intervention->setWho($infopm);
    $intervention->setInfoPm($comment);
    $intervention->setComment($location);
    $sn->flush();

    $response=array("id" => $id, "status" => "success");

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Thank you very much

**Update of my code after the replys:**

I have update this in my twig template:

> save: "rest->{{ path('api_i_post', { trialid: trial.id }) }}",

If I look in the profiler of the ajax request, I see it is here:

> Key   Value
>
> trialid  "1"

But I still don't figure how to get it in my post request (the trial_id is still null right now)

I've tried the following:

```
    /**
 * @Rest\Post("/api_i/", name="api_i_post")
 * @Rest\RequestParam(name="trialid")
 *
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function postAction(Request $request, ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    $data = new Intervention;
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $action = $request->get('action');
    $daadala = $request->get('daadala');
    $date = $request->get('date');
    $week = $request->get('week');
    $infopm = $request->get('info_pm');
    $comment = $request->get('comment');
    $location = $request->get('location');
    $trial = $paramFetcher->get('trialid');

    $data->setAction($action);
    $data->setDaadala($daadala);
    $data->setDate($date);
    $data->setWeek($week);
    $data->setWho($infopm);
    $data->setInfoPm($comment);
    $data->setComment($location);
    $data->setTrial($trial);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();

    $lastid = $data->getId();

    $response=array("id" => $id, "status" => "success", "newid" => $lastid);
    return new JsonResponse($response);

    $view = View::create(array("newid" => $lastid, "id" => $id, "status" => "success"));
    return $this->handleView($view);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get post value you need to do this inside your post action:

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
     $postData = $request->request->all();
```

Then you have an array of value like:

```
$id = $postData['id'];
```

For the PUT you need this:

```
public function putAction(int $id, Request $request)
{
    $putData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

And then to treieve a value like this:

```
$id = $putData['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think the id I retrieve this way is the id of the database intervention. I'm trying to get the id of the datatabase trial (the relational trial_id in the database intervention). The trial id is the id in the url (or in the trial object of this page) and this is the one I'm having hard time to add in my post request. Any clue?

Comment: inside the put for example I have added inside the declarations parameter $id taken by url automatically @jonibegoode

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the FosRestBundle, if so, you can use annotations to retrieve your url parameters :

```
/**
 * @Rest\Put("/api_i/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 */
public function putAction($id)
{
    // you now have access to $id
    ...
}
```

If you want to allow additionnal parameters for your route but not in the uri, you can use RequestParam with annotations :

```
/**
 * @Rest\Put("/my-route/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 *
 * @Rest\RequestParam(name="param1")
 * @Rest\RequestParam(name="param2")
 *
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 * @param int $id
 */
public function putAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher, $id)
{
    $param1 = $paramFetcher->get('param1');
    ....
}
```

Be sure to check the fosRestBundle documentation to see everything you can do (such as typing the params, making them mandatory or not, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure this is what I need though. The id in the route is the id of the table intervention. I'm trying to retrieve the trial_id (which is the id of the url of the page trial/1) I didn't know about the ParamFetcher, Thanks for pointing me to this but I'm not quite sure how to use it. I've update my code in the original message, but it still doesn't get the trial_id